# HOW CAN COMBINE 4 QUERY IN 1 QUERY ? (ORACLE SQL)

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

HELLO I WANT COMBINE QUERY.

select * from table where code='?';

select * from table where code='?' or code='?';

select * from table where code='?' or code='?' or code='?';

select * from table where code='?' or code='?' or code='?' or code='?';

i make this 4 query but i want combine them. how i can?

and code has 4 value like 1,2,3,4
please help me!
(i'm using oracle 11, SQL Developer)

Comment: It makes _no sense_ to “combine” such queries against the same table as as ‘or’ is used. Some keywords that can be used to start a search: `JOIN`, `UNION ALL`, `IN`, which might help formulate a reasonable question, especially considering all these keywords can “combine” in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure from the way question is worded but I think you may be looking for a `IN` statement?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE code IN ('1' ,'2' ,'3' ,'4');
```

for more on this, visit

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions014.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can use union all for example

```
select * from table where code='?';
union all
select * from table where code='?' or code='?';
union all
select * from table where code='?' or code='?' or code='?';
union all
select * from table where code='?' or code='?' or code='?' or code='?';
```

or you can use IN operator like

```
select * from table where code in ('?',?','?','?')
```

Comment: thank you! I can learned something new!(union all) Thank you!